# InsertOne mongodb in .net core does not return result

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, .net-core, mongodb-query

i am new in mongodb And when i use InsertOne Or InsertMany methods does not return any result.
how can i be sure data were inserted.
I Use MongoDB.Driver Version 2.10.3
Sorry for my language

Comment: I haven't used C# in awhile but it looks like they introduced an await operator like JavaScript. My guess is that's your issue.

Comment: @Chance I believe C# had await before it was introduced in JS :)

Comment: @mickl interesting, I had no idea. I really need to look into C# again. I moved on to Rails and then Node when it was released. I think I left .Net behind sometime around 3.5/4.0. I remember really missing the lambdas that were introduced with LINQ but JS eventually got them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the implementation [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/984598aa450155f01d3d661d092139e67069432c/src/MongoDB.Driver/MongoCollectionBase.cs#L450).

Basically whenever something goes wrong like there's a connection errror or your insert violates unique key you will get a `MongoWriteException`. So your code may look like this:

```
try
{
    collection.InsertOne(document);
}
catch (MongoWriteException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

There's another method in MongoDB - [bulkWrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) - which might execute some operations successfully and fail for the other ones. In such case [MongoDB .NET driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/4b2a63af6faddfe8716074a525c3de3d1600c974/src/MongoDB.Driver/MongoCollectionImpl.cs#L202) returns an instance of `BulkWriteResult<TDocument>` class.